# How to concatenate multiple videos while maintaining original aspect ratio?

Tags: ffmpeg, aspect

Is it possible to concatenate many videos with different aspect ratio? So in the end every video segment maintains the original aspect ratio.

I've tried the following FFmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -y -filter_complex "[0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0] concat=unsafe=1:n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" out.mp4
```

I'm using **unsafe=1** which works almost perfect.

The only issue is that some videos stretch. 
So, how can I concatenate different videos while maintaining the original quality and aspect ratio?

Bonus: Is something wrong with using **unsafe=1**?. The param name 'unsafe' implies that maybe I should trust it only under certain conditions.

UPDATE

---

I tried @llogan answer but it still produces the same result.
Command I tried is

```
 ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]scale=720:576:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=720:576:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[v0];[1]scale=720:576:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=720:576:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[v1];[v0][0:a:0][v1][1:a:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" out.mp4
```

Complete log:

`ffmpeg version N-94862-g944d76a3e0 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190807
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 35.100 / 56. 35.100
  libavcodec     58. 56.101 / 58. 56.101
  libavformat    58. 32.104 / 58. 32.104
  libavdevice    58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavfilter     7. 58.102 /  7. 58.102
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000028a5a96a180] st: 0 edit list: 2 Missing key frame while searching for timestamp: 0
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000028a5a96a180] st: 0 edit list 2 Cannot find an index entry before timestamp: 0.
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 2019-06-04T10:36:32.000000Z
  Duration: 00:01:47.31, start: 0.080000, bitrate: 1354 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], 1194 kb/s, 24.96 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 20000k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-06-04T10:36:32.000000Z
      handler_name    : FOUNDATION MEDIA HANDLER
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-06-04T10:36:32.000000Z
      handler_name    : FOUNDATION MEDIA HANDLER
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    title           : 914153178930195
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
  Duration: 00:00:54.73, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 155 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 224x400 [SAR 190:189 DAR 76:135], 120 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #1:1(und): Audio: aac (HE-AACv2) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 31 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
File 'out.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> scale
  Stream #0:1 (aac) -> concat:in0:a0
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> scale
  Stream #1:1 (aac) -> concat:in1:a0
  concat:out:v0 -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  concat:out:a0 -> Stream #0:1 (aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0000028a5bd91600] Warning: data is not aligned! This can lead to a speed loss
[libx264 @ 0000028a5aa1e600] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0000028a5aa1e600] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0000028a5aa1e600] profile High, level 3.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0000028a5aa1e600] 264 - core 158 r2984 3759fcb - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2019 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.32.104
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 720x576 [SAR 1:1 DAR 5:4], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.56.101 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.56.101 aac
frame= 4043 fps=127 q=-1.0 Lsize=   17387kB time=00:02:41.78 bitrate= 880.4kbits/s speed= 5.1x
video:14740kB audio:2512kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.781354%
[libx264 @ 0000028a5aa1e600] frame I:27    Avg QP:19.86  size: 31123
[libx264 @ 0000028a5aa1e600] frame P:1424  Avg QP:23.10  size:  7119
[libx264 @ 0000028a5aa1e600] frame B:2592  Avg QP:26.01  size:  1588
[libx264 @ 0000028a5aa1e600] consecutive B-frames:  4.5% 24.6% 16.2% 54.7%
[libx264 @ 0000028a5aa1e600] mb I  I16..4: 14.8% 42.4% 42.7%
[libx264 @ 0000028a5aa1e600] mb P  I16..4:  2.2%  3.8%  1.7%  P16..4: 32.9% 13.8%  6.4%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:39.0%
[libx264 @ 0000028a5aa1e600] mb B  I16..4:  0.2%  0.2%  0.1%  B16..8: 28.5%  4.3%  0.7%  direct: 1.1%  skip:65.0%  L0:40.5% L1:53.2% BI: 6.3%
[libx264 @ 0000028a5aa1e600] 8x8 transform intra:47.2% inter:58.6%
[libx264 @ 0000028a5aa1e600] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 46.9% 56.9% 18.1% inter: 9.6% 11.2% 0.3%
[libx264 @ 0000028a5aa1e600] i16 v,h,dc,p: 47% 29%  9% 16%
[libx264 @ 0000028a5aa1e600] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 28% 18% 28%  4%  4%  5%  4%  5%  4%
[libx264 @ 0000028a5aa1e600] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 37% 19% 11%  5%  6%  8%  5%  7%  4%
[libx264 @ 0000028a5aa1e600] i8c dc,h,v,p: 50% 21% 24%  5%
[libx264 @ 0000028a5aa1e600] Weighted P-Frames: Y:2.3% UV:0.6%
[libx264 @ 0000028a5aa1e600] ref P L0: 67.3% 16.4% 11.9%  4.4%  0.1%
[libx264 @ 0000028a5aa1e600] ref B L0: 89.6%  9.0%  1.4%
[libx264 @ 0000028a5aa1e600] ref B L1: 98.6%  1.4%
[libx264 @ 0000028a5aa1e600] kb/s:746.65
[aac @ 0000028a5a9a1e00] Qavg: 1320.561`

Answer (score 3):

> how can I concatenate different videos while maintaining the original quality and aspect ratio?

## using concat demuxer

Make text file containing:

```
file '1.mp4'
file '2.mp4'
```

Run `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

This is fast and does not re-encode, so it will maintain the original quality, but it may not be supported or play correctly by your player or device. This assumes both inputs have the same formats, number of streams, timebase, etc, and the only difference is width x height and duration.

## using concat filter

Use this if the first method doesn't work or if you have to re-encode anyway.

Add the scale, pad, setsar filters, and choose the desired output width x height. Example for 1280x720:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[v0];[1]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[v1];[v0][0:a:0][v1][1:a:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" out.mp4
```

If you would rather crop instead of pad and/or avoid upscaling see examples in [Resizing videos with ffmpeg to fit specific size](https://superuser.com/a/1136305/110524).

As for "original quality" you would have to use a lossless encoder, not a lossy encoder. Add `-crf 0` to enable lossless when encoding with libx264, but note the files will be huge. If you mean "visually, but not technically lossless" then use `-crf 18`. See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264).

#### unsafe

> Is something wrong with using unsafe=1?. The param name 'unsafe' implies that maybe I should trust it only under certain conditions.

Without `unsafe` it will fail if segments have a different format or vary in some attributes, but with `unsafe` it will not fail but the resulting output may not be compatible or playable with your player or device.

Comment: Video still stretches. Small aspect ratio works fine but videos with big aspect ratios stretch. The result is the same as with the command of the question(unsafe=1). I'm thinking maybe if small aspect ratio adds padding, maybe that would work.

Comment: @Antony Provide your command and the complete log.

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: @Antony I was lazy and assumed square pixels. Try `"[0]scale=iw*sar:ih,setsar=1[ref];[1][ref]scale2ref=w=oh*mdar:h=ih[s][v0];[s]pad=1024:576:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[v1];[v0][0:a:0][v1][1:a:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]"` It can be also done without needing to enter any WxH values, but that can be dealt with later.

Comment: Works! Please update your answer so I can accept it. If WxH values could be skipped that would be useful. Also, can you please explain the `pad=1024:576` part?

Comment: How can I remove WxH values? It's really important to make it more dynamic.

Comment: @Antony See the [scale2ref](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale2ref) filter.

Comment: FFmpeg documentation is very poor. There are other questions too without proper answers(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45361936/ffmpeg-scale2ref-explanation). Please if you can help.

Comment: Please @llogan if you can I really need help.

Comment: @Antony I don't recall what I was going to suggest. pad values will be the same result as the scale filter. So in a variable outside of the command do iw*sar of the first input and dump that into pad.

Comment: I understand what you mean. This works good for 2 videos for concatenating videos. I'm trying to concatenate multiple videos. Do you know any way to do this? Either by scaling videos one by one or scale & concatenate all at once.

Comment: @Antony You can do it all in one command.